# Latexmk not using pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, latexmk

I have a `.tex` file which attempts to `\includegraphics` with a `.pdf` file.

This is perfectly possible when explicitly running `pdflatex` but doesn't work with `latexmk` because `latexmk` runs with `latex` and not `pdflatex`. ([This SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17737/31839) pointed me to the `latex` vs. `pdflatex` problem.)

I'm interested in getting my compilation to work with `latexmk` because I'm using the Vim plugin [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). Is there a way?

Comment: It doesn't say anywhere in the answer you link to that `latexmk` runs with `latex` rather than `pdflatex`. But if you run `latexmk` with the argument `-pdf`, it should compile with `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you run `latexmk` with the argument `-pdf`, it will compile with `pdflatex`.

In TeXWorks:

[image]

On Linux, change the `~/.latexmkrc' file as per [this SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123183/how-do-i-set-up-my-config-file-to-have-latexmk-default-to-making-a-pdf).